# Do we need to learn javascript first before writing code in phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm going to write phantomjs script to use it in automation testing. Do I need to learn javascript first?

source: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with java

Comment: That depends on what tool you'll use with phantomjs, if it's casperjs yes, you need java script, if you use selenium you can use various programming languages such as java python and ruby, there are plenty more.

Comment: yes i configured phantomjs jar with eclipse, so can I use java? But phantom.exit() command how to use it in java?

Comment: Because after o/p prints also, eclipse isn't stopped, so in which way I need to use exit() command, ps: driver.close and quit commands not working.

Comment: If you have a specific question about PhantomJS+Java+Selenium, then you should ask it, but please check out previous questions on this site. There are a lot of questions asking about non-exiting PhantomJS processes when calling `driver.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not required to learn JavaScript; you can continue coding in Java while using PhantomJS. For a working example with Java and PhantomJS, please have a look at [this](http://www.guru99.com/selenium-with-htmlunit-driver-phantomjs.html).

1. In order to use PhantomJS with Seleniun, one has to use GhostDriver. GhostDriver is a implementation of Webdriver Wire protocol in simple JS for PhantomJS.
2. The latest release of PhatomJS has integrated GhostDriver and there is no need to separately install it.

Installation:

1. You need Eclipse with Selenium installed
2. Download from here http://phantomjs.org/download.html
3. Extract the downloaded folder to Program Files
4. Download the PhantomJS Driver from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver/1.1.0.
5. Add the jar to your project.

A Java working example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
File file = new File("C:/Program Files/phantomjs-2.0.0-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");             
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());        
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();   
driver.get("http://www.google.com");         
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));  
element.sendKeys("Guru99");                 
element.submit();                   
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());      
driver.quit();          
           }
```

Comment: thank you, I'll work on this and if share you the o/p

Comment: hi above one is worked, but sometimes "Unable to find element with xpath 'html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]..." xpath ocurring, for the script to check that element I'm giving more wait time, but still this is throwing error.

Comment: try to use different locator stratgey

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to learn JavaScript in order to write PhantomJS *scripts*. You could also learn CoffeeScript in order to write PhantomJS 1.x *scripts*.

If you don't want to write PhantomJS scripts, then you can use any language under the sun to instruct PhantomJS to do something through Selenium and the WebDriver wire protocol.